# Binomial coefficient question? Part D?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Jinbao produces tubas and ships them in lots of twenty.
>
> Suppose that 60% of all such lots contain no defective tubas, 30% 
>   contain one defective, and 10% contain two defectives.  Now suppose 
>   that a lot is inspected, with two tubas being selected from it at 
>   random, and neither is found to be defective.
>
> a) What is the probability that there are no defectives in that lot?
>
> b) What is the probability that there is one defective in that lot?
>
> c) What is the probability that there are two defectives in that lot?
>
> d) Suppose that the inspected lot is from a shipping container that 
>   contains 10 lots, and the other 9 lots were not inspected.  What is 
>   the probability that there are no defectives in that container?

I've done part a,b,c. Any idea how to do part d?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the probability of 19 good given 10 good. An idea might be to draw a tree diagram and investigate each arm.

Comment: No.  (d) is trying to find the probability of all 10 *lots* good given the 1 *lot* tested had a good sample (2 *tubas* from 20).  But, yes, the conditional tree diagram might help.

Comment: ah, sorry, I misread it. Just an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

> d) Suppose that the inspected lot is from a shipping container that contains 10 lots, and the other 9 lots were not inspected. What is the probability that there are no defectives in that container?

Since the probabilities of finding defectives in the other containers are *conditionally independent* of finding defectives in the first, then this is simply: the probability of the tested lot being good, given that its samples were both good, times the probabilities that each of the remaining lots are good.

Let $D_x$ count the number of defectives in lot of $20$ tubas, for lot number $x$, and $T_x$ count the number of defectives in the sampled two tubas.

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{P}(\mathop{\cap}_{x=1}^{10} D_x=0\mid T_1=0) & = \operatorname{P}(D_1=0 \mid T_1=0)\times\prod_{x=2}^{10} \operatorname{P}(D_x=0) \\ ~ & = \operatorname{P}(D=0\mid T=0)\times(\operatorname{P}(D=0))^9\end{align}$$

Where $P(D=0\mid T=0)$ the the answer to part (a). (The probability of no defectives in a lot given no defectives in the sample.)